# How to list a 2 million files directory in java without having an "out of memory" exception

Tags: java, file, file-io, out-of-memory

I have to deal with a directory of about 2 million xml's to be processed.

I've already solved the processing distributing  the work between machines and threads using queues and everything goes right.

But now the big problem is the bottleneck of reading the directory with the 2 million files in order to fill the queues incrementally.

I've tried using the `File.listFiles()` method, but it gives me a java `out of memory: heap space` exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but what OS does not support that? Living in 1950? I Know of various tools blowing, for example on windows (explorer getting AWFULLY slow), but the file system supports it.

Comment: @TomTom: FAT32 (old, but by no means 1950 era, and still quite common) has a limit of files per directory óf 65k.

Comment: But assuming someone uses that is neglegient - except for devices not supporting it, and then the problem - guess what - would not be "problem listing the files".

Comment: I completly agree it's been a bad option not to store them in a hierarch way.

The file system is NTFS. Here you can read the limits:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Hi @Fgblanch did u find the solution cuz i have same problem, Please help.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Could you explain how you solved the problem please?

Comment: @AhmadAlkhateeb  Since we couldn't use Java 7,  we found a pattern in the filenames and them wrote a script to store them in a hierarchical way (much more efficient). So my suggestion use Java 7+ or try to rearrange the files into multiple folders without querying the whole list

Comment: @IbrahimNadir find the solution in the comment above

Comment: @Fgblanch if i use FileNameFilter, will that help in avoiding the memory exception? I can also use Java7, what is the best solution in this case. The files i would be processing would be around 80GB(each around 1mb or less). Can you suggest which Java7 library would help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, do you have any possibility to use Java 7? There you have a `FileVisitor` and the `Files.walkFileTree`, which should probably work within your memory constraints.

<strike>Otherwise, the only way I can think of is to use `File.listFiles(FileFilter filter)` with a filter that always returns `false` (ensuring that the full array of files is never kept in memory), but that catches the files to be processed along the way, and perhaps puts them in a producer/consumer queue or writes the file-names to disk for later traversal.</strike>

Alternatively, if you control the names of the files, or if they are named in some nice way, you could process the files in chunks using a filter that accepts filenames on the form `file0000000`-`filefile0001000` then `file0001000`-`filefile0002000` and so on.

If the names are *not* named in a nice way like this, you could try filtering them based on the hash-code of the file-name, which is supposed to be fairly evenly distributed over the set of integers.

---

**Update:** Sigh. Probably won't work. Just had a look at the listFiles implementation:

```
public File[] listFiles(FilenameFilter filter) {
    String ss[] = list();
    if (ss == null) return null;
    ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ss.length ; i++) {
        if ((filter == null) || filter.accept(this, ss[i])) {
            v.add(new File(ss[i], this));
        }
    }
    return (File[])(v.toArray(new File[v.size()]));
}
```

so it will probably fail at the first line anyway... Sort of disappointing. I believe your best option is to put the files in different directories.

Btw, could you give an example of a file name? Are they "guessable"? Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    tryToOpen(String.format("file%05d", i))
```

Comment: Java 7 is not an option right now.

Currently i'm trying the filter option. Thankfully the files have a hierarchy written in the filename. So this option could work.

Comment: aioobe effectively it didn't work. I've found the filenames are "guessables" :) so i'll do it the other way around:

Generate the filenames and then go to the folder and try to reach them. 

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 9):

If Java 7 is not an option, this hack will work (for UNIX):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ls", "-f", "/path"});
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (null != (line = reader.readLine())) {
    if (line.startsWith("."))
        continue;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The -f parameter will speed it up (from `man ls`):

```
-f     do not sort, enable -aU, disable -lst
```

Comment: It's not a hack but a way to deal with the limited Java API ;) 
But it should add support for other operating systems, and it would be prima ;)

Answer (score 9):

In case you can use Java 7 this can be done in this way and you won't have those out of memory problems.

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\path\\with\\lots\\of\\files");
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                // here you have the files to process
                System.out.println(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
               return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
              return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`File.list()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()) instead of `File.listFiles()` - the `String` objects it returns consume less memory than the `File` objects, and (more importantly, depending on the location of the directory) they don't contain the full path name.

Then, construct `File` objects as needed when processing the result.

However, this will not work for arbitrarily large directories either. It's an overall better idea to organize your files in a hierarchy of directories so that no single directory has more than a few thousand entries.

Answer (score 4):

This also requires Java 7, but it's simpler than the `Files.walkFileTree` answer if you just want to list the contents of a directory and not walk the whole tree:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/some/directory");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
    for (Path path : stream) {
        handleFile(path.toFile());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    handleException(e);
}
```

The implementation of `DirectoryStream` is platform-specific and never calls `File.list` or anything like it, instead using the Unix or Windows system calls that iterate over a directory one entry at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with Apache FileUtils library. No memory problem. I did check with visualvm.

```
  Iterator<File> it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder, null, true);
  while (it.hasNext())
  {
     File fileEntry = (File) it.next();
  }
```

Hope that helps.
bye

Comment: FileUtils (checked with 2.4) internally uses File#list() as well, so the same problem with big directories will appear. Note that #iterateFiles() just returns the .iterator() from the result of #listFiles().

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on Windows, it seems like you should have simply used ProcessBuilder to start something like "cmd /k dir /b target_directory", capture the output of that, and route it into a file. You can then process that file a line at a time, reading the file names out and dealing with them.

Better late than never? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store 2 million files in the same directory anyway? I can imagine it slows down access terribly on the OS level already.

I would definitely want to have them divided into subdirectories (e.g. by date/time of creation) already before processing. But if it is not possible for some reason, could it be done during processing? E.g. move 1000 files queued for Process1 into Directory1, another 1000 files for Process2 into Directory2 etc. Then each process/thread sees only the (limited number of) files portioned for it.

Comment: Diving them its a problem in it's own. I'm thinking on that as well at OS bash functions.

It is not possible to do it while processing because the exception comes when trying to list the directory programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

At fist you could try to increase the memory of your JVM with passing -Xmx1024m e.g.

Comment: I have a feeling this won't fix the problem, and the JVM will just run out of memory *slightly* later.

Comment: @Piskvor If so, I guess there is no way to solve this issue. Whatever you use to parse the os file system will need a certain amound of bytes - with 2million files this can fastly become too much.

Comment: you don't need to keep all your data in RAM at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full stack trace of the OOM exception to identify where the bottleneck is, as well as a short, complete Java program showing the behaviour you see.

It is most likely because you collect all of the two million entries in memory, and they don't fit.  Can you increase heap space?

Answer (score 0):

If file names follow certain rules, you can use `File.list(filter)` instead of `File.listFiles` to get manageable portions of file listing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I developed malware scanning application. My solution is execute shell command to list all files. It's faster than recursively methods to browse folder by folder.

see more about shell command here: http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-ls

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -R /");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        //TODO: Read the stream to get a list of file path.
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use listFiles with a special FilenameFilter. The first time the FilenameFilter is sent to listFiles it accepts the first 1000 files and then saves them as visited.

The next time FilenameFilter is sent to listFiles, it ignores the first 1000 visited files and returns the next 1000, and so on until complete.

Comment: The very first line in listFiles (even with FilenameFilter) creates an array of strings - each string a file name in the directory. Also, pointed out by @aioobe.

Answer (score -1):

As a first approach you might try tweaking some JVM memory settings, e.g. increase heap size as it was suggested or even use AggressiveHeap option.
Taking into account the large amount of files, this may not help, then I would suggest to workaround the problem. Create several files with filenames in each, say 500k filenames per file and read from them.

Comment: JVM tuning can only be done up to an extent. That won't solve the general problem of a very large input.

Answer (score -3):

Try this, it works to me, but I hadn't so many documents...

```
File dir = new File("directory");
String[] children = dir.list();
if (children == null) {
   //Either dir does not exist or is not a  directory
  System.out.print("Directory doesn't  exist\n");
}
else {
  for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {   
    // Get filename of file or directory   
    String filename = children[i];  
}
```

Comment: It's directly what is not working for asker, he have many files