# Reading a file in a directory in java and storing its offset in the directory

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to be able to read files from a directory in java without the worry of getting an out of memory exception because `files.listfiles()` and `files.list()` can only hold so much. I also want to know if there is a way to store the offset of the file in the directory so I can store that number and not have to iterate through the directory again to find it, is this possible?

Right now I'm using Jaime Hablutzel's answer from another question to go through the directory but wondering if I can store the file offset in the directory to go directly to it next time.

My thought was to store the filenames in a text file then store a count to record the number of characters until each new line was encountered which is another filename then use the RandomAccessFile seek() method to go directory to that line from the saved count.

[How to list 2 million files in a directory in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139073/how-to-list-a-2-million-files-directory-in-java-without-having-an-out-of-memory/14241968#14241968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved my problem on what I wanted to do. I created an offset to each file I stored in a textfile by taking the length + 1 of each filename and adding it to the offset then writing it to a file.

```
 public static void readOffsets()
{
    try {
        File file = new File("indexFile.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("indexFile2.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        String line;
        int offset = 0;
        pw.write(offset + "\n");
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int length = line.length();
            offset += length + 1;
            pw.write(offset + "\n");

        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then when seeking the offset using the randomaccessfile I would get the correct filename.

```
 public static void seekOffset()
{
    try {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("IndexFile.txt", "r");
        file.seek(693);
        System.out.println(file.readLine());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
        {

        }
}
```