# out of memory listing files on android (how to iterate over lots of files)

Tags: java, android, performance, out-of-memory

our android app generates some files. depending on the user's activity up to 500-
600 a day (this is a business request so it cannot be changed :) ).

when and while there is a wifi connection, the app uploads regularly these files and the ones that are up are deleted.

now the problem is when users have over a long time no connection.
when a wifi connection is established we get a out of memory error.

The files are retrieves using File.listFiles - which seems to get the whole list in memory - causing the problem.

The [DirectoryStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) and [FileVisitor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) are not yet available.

Is there a way to iterate over the files, not loading their names in an array?

Comment: [Visit this link it may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139073/how-to-list-a-2-million-files-directory-in-java-without-having-an-out-of-memory)

Comment: `The files are retrieves using File.listFiles - which seems to get the whole list in memory - causing the problem.`. No that will not cause an out of memory problem is my experience. 600 or 1000 is not much. Try to find the real cause.

Comment: `The DirectoryStream and FileVisitor are not yet available.` What do you want to say with that?

Comment: we have like 600 files a day. 2-3 weeks without wifi and we are at 12000. then on next connect we get the our of memory.

Comment: The DirectoryStream and FileVisitor are not yet available. - i mean they are in Android O Developer Preview. But not in API Level 25

Comment: why the vote to close it? this is a legit problem that we have on android.